# Center align the picture

Tags: image, alignment, center

Why this image is not centrally align?

> ```
>  <div style=" width:70%; margin:0 auto; padding:0.2%; border:1px solid #000; ">
>  <img src="images/social.png" width="227" height="68" style="border:1px solid #000; 
>   border-radius:5px; width:auto; margin:0 auto; display:block;" /></div>
> ```

Its the simple question. Any quick solution please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Its simple try using line height property and set its value in px equivalent to the height of the container e.g
//container

```
<div class="container" align="center">
<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/46a9844d6e504212a85bc72ddd7dd829.png"       width="40" height="40">
 </div>
//css
.container{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```